# Usage of "new" action necessary for json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, controller

If I'm using my rails app to mainly respond to json, is having a "new" or "edit" action that returns an empty object in json still necessary/useful? For example:

```
def new
  @post = Post.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json  { render :json => @post }
  end
end
```

I feel like I can just get away from making a server call by completely building the forms in html

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, yes, you can exclude that action if you don't need special default field values and are assembling your form fields manually.